# Django - Many-to-many with intermediate model - display in template with Generic DetailView

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

A Work has many contributors, through the Contributors model which defines contributor (an Entity - group or person), role (author, editor, translator), and attribution certainty (definite, traditional, conjectural, etc).

To complicate things, several additional classes extend Work ( Text, Music... and their subclasses) and Entity (Person, Group... and different types of Groups) .... and its all polymorphic to the base class... 
The case I happen to be working on at the moment is a HymnText written by a Person, but but I *think* that is irrelevant to the current question, because I'm referencing the base classes (and successfully, otherwise).

I'm trying to use a Generic DetailView. I am about as far as knowing (assuming) that I need to extend the DetailView in order to access the list of contributors... but not sure how to extend it.

**Models:**

```
class Entry(PolymorphicModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Work(Entry):
    contributors = models.ManyToManyField(Entity, through='Contribution', blank=True)

class Entity(Entry):
    pass

class Text(Work):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)

class HymnText(Text):
    meter = models.ForeignKey(Meter, blank=True)


class Contribution(models.Model):
    contributor = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work)
    role = models.ForeignKey(ContributionRole)
    attribution_certainty = models.ForeignKey(AttributionCertainty, blank=True)
```

**The relevant urlpattern**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'hymntext/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)/$', EntryView.as_view(model=HymnText, template_name="cmi_index/entry.html"), name="hymntext" )
]
```

**The nothing-I-have-done to create EntryView**

```
class EntryView(DetailView):
    pass
```

**What I am attempting to do in the Template (doesn't do squat)**

```
{% for contributor in hymntext.contributors.all %}
   <br>{{ contributor.role.name }}: {{ contributor.contributor.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Interestingly, in the output...**

I get the line break and colon for each contributor saved to the entry. So the template knows they are there, I just can't (don't know how to) access their properties.

---

UPDATE:

Apparently most of the info is available, I just am a bit unsure how to get it.

When I change the template to this:

```
{% for contributor in hymntext.contributors.all %}
   <br>{{ contributor.role }}: {{ contributor.name }} -- {{contributor|pprint}}
 {% endfor %}
```

Some of the contributor details leak through in the output:

```
: David Haas -- <Person: David Haas (Person)> 
: John Newton -- <Person: John Newton (Person)>
```

If I can get names of people, surely I can get contribution roles and whatever else, right...? I haven't implemented any changes to the View - this is all coming from the Generic Detail View.

Comment: Did my answer work for you or are you still having trouble?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I haven't had time today to try to implement it, but honestly I didn't understand it that well. I am hoping that I will figure it out once I started trying things, but just reading it a handful of times I'm a bit confused what is happening (like, where does "contribution_set" come from, for example), and how to actually access this stuff from a template. Any additional explanation or a more full code example would be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe my bigger question from reading your comments is - why can't I bring the full set of contributors into the template so that i can iterate through them and access their attributes? That doesn't seem like what your two options are doing? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer was actually easier than it seemed.

The through-field data is actually available in the template via the 
Generic View (as I suspected). The `[through-model]_set` gets it, and then you can just access all the attributes. Here is my Jinja template code

```
{% for contribution in hymntext.contribution_set.all %}
   <br>{{ contribution.role.name }}: {{ contribution.contributor.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

which outputs (in this particular fake example):

> creator: David Haas
>   translator: John Newton

Comment: I had a hard time understanding your answer due to the complex models but thanks. It helped a lot ;)

Comment: Could you please help me with this [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73627756/django-polymorphic-admin-website-error-displaying-inline-admin-with-manytomany) ?

Answer (score 1):

One of these (executed in your view class before they're passed to the template as context variables) might help:

Here is a [part of the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) that my help you. In order to get information like `role` from a `HymnText` `contributor`:

```
contributor.contribution_set.get(work=hymntext).role
```

OR you can call the `Contribution` model:

```
# Loop through the hymntext contributors...
roles = []; names = []
for contributor in hymntext.contributors:
  contribution = Contribution.objects.get(work=hymntext, contributor=contributor)
  roles.push(contribution.role)
  names.push(contributor.name) # I assume you define this in your Entity model

# Then set up your context variables and render the template
```

Comment: So I ended not actually needing to edit the view class, as the Generic Detail View provides what I need. But your answer did help me find what I was looking for. So thank you very much for that.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped a bit.